# problem of conditional visibility and page breaks with rectangles in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, conditional-statements, visibility

I am trying to insert a conditional page break, actually i had a report of 50 pages with invoices each invoice is 3 pages long so i need a paghebreak for the 2nd invoice t printon the next page as i need the whole report ot print back to back,so i inserted one page break,so this starts the next invoice to start on 4th page but i want next invoice to start on 5th page which is a new page and i inserted another pagebreak there  if the 3rd page of previous report is not filled, but if the 3rd page is filled and the invoice goes on to 4th page then i dont need this additional page break

I tried doign this by taking two rectangles
--first with inert page break at the end
--second with conditional visibility of the rectangle2 and with page break at the start.
and the condition for the rectangle2 to be visible is like

Visibility---hidden and expression is 
--iif(count(id field of the table in third page)>=24,true,false)

i.e 3rd page accomodates atmost of 24 records and if the records are more than 24 i dont need another pagebreak and i am hiding the rectangle2 only if records are less than 24 i need another page break and i am not hiding the rectanlge2

BUT THE VISIBILITY IS NOT WORKING AND THE RECTANGLE2 IS NOT WORKING.

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a column to the data source, such as InvoiceNumber, that you could define as a page-breaking group. Then the page should break before a new Invoice and at the end of each of your rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with SSRS 2005. It's very unfortunate actually. Have a look at [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439/conditional-visibility-and-page-breaks-with-sql-server-2005-reporting-services).