# Report has paging even with interactive size zero 0 in SSRS

Tags: reporting, paging, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report in SSRS 2005 that consists of three subreports, all four of which have their interactive size set to zero. The three subreports are contained in a list. However, the report still pages (verb) at what looks like 8.5in X 11in. The paging is not due to page breaks because there are none and sometimes the reports cut off in the middle and continue on the next page.

What else causes paging besides the interactive size?

**UPDATE:** I am referring to web pages specifically. The printed/exported size works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fixed by setting the list's `Visibility` | `Hidden` property to any expression that returns false. I set it to `1=0` and suddenly the interactive report stopped paging.

This is not so much a fix as a hack because, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439/conditional-visibility-and-page-breaks-with-sql-server-2005-reporting-services), the visibility property stopping pagination is an SSRS bug. However, I believe the issue I was having is also a bug, so I don't feel quite as dirty using a hack.

**I'm still open to anyone explaining why the original issue was happening.**

Answer (score 3):

I can see that the "Page Size" prorperty also matters apart from the "Interactive Size".

Set the "Height" property under "Page Size" property for the main report that contains the subreport as "455" inches that is the maximum size for the page height. If the data is more than that then it will be in the other page I think we cannot avoid this.

Comment: I realized that I didn't explicitly say webpages in my original question. I've updated the question appropriately.