# How to remove a page break on a tablix when the tablix is not visible?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Tablix on my report with the "Add a page break before" property enabled.
The Tablix also has the following expression for its Visibility:

```
=iif(Parameters!ShowAppendix.Value = "Yes", False, True)
```

When I run my report and `ShowAppendix` is `"No"`, the tablix is hidden but there is still a page break inserted.

How can I make it so that no page break is included when the element is not visible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Visibility and Page Breaks with SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439/conditional-visibility-and-page-breaks-with-sql-server-2005-reporting-services)

Comment: What version of SSRS and visual studio are you using? I tested this in Visual Studio 2015 and did not experience this issue.